# Regex - IP Address can be repeated with new line

Tags: regex

I want to know how can i match one ip address for per line?

I'v tried this but working for a single ip address with a single new line char.

> ^((([0-9]{1,3})\.?){4}\n?)$

Sample data:

```
35.24.74.12
22.54.12.23
```

Test url: http://regex101.com/r/yW9xT7

Result **UPDATE**

New regex:

> /^(([0-9]{1,3}\.?){4})$/m

New results (with php preg_match_all):

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "123.234.123.21"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "232.123.21.42"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "123.234.123.21"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "232.123.21.42"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "21"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "42"
  }
}
```

New problem:

There are three matches. I just want first result.

Comment: I hope you've considered IPv6 addresses too... :-)

Comment: @PeteVerdon Nope :) Not for now. Just ipv4 now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
```

Comment: This is not i was looking for. Your answer is just controlling ip address with certain rules. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex with `m flag (multiline)`:

```
^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$
```

Comment: Can only be just one new line for per ip address.

Comment: Yes this will expect one IP per line

Comment: What about new lines without any ip addresses? Think of users pressed enter a few times without typing anything?

Comment: Those lines won't be matched. If you provide your sample inout and expected output in question I can probably understand it better.

Comment: I'm using symfony validator plugin. In my validation.yml rules are can be set with regex patterns. My pattern is exactly this now. `/^((([0-9]{1,3})\.?){4})$/gm`

Comment: Have you tried: `/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/gm` if something isn't working then provide your expected match out of it.

Comment: Yes i'v tried this. [link](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) working on here. But not working with my application. I will upvote your answer because of working on that url.

Comment: As I wrote I can help further if you can reproduce problem in any of the online regex testers such as http://regex101.com

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to escape the dot. Also here is how you avoid the dot at the end.

```
^(([0-9]{1,3}\.){4}[0-9]{1,3})$
```

A more proper regex would only accept numbers between 0 and 255 like this:

```
[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]
```

Which gives:

```
^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
```

In order to match multiple lines you can repeat the above and include new lines in between each repetition like this:

```
^((([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])[\r\n]+)*(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice but i just want to know how can i get it work with multiple lines.

Comment: Just use the last line.

Comment: Nope. Even could not catch any ip address.